# Multicriterial filtering operators in Datasets

Tags: dataset, filtering

How to generate a long `Select` query with Dataset-based syntactic sugar? For instance, let we generate the dataset

```
keys="key" ~~ (ToString@#) & /@ Range[30]; 
data = Dataset@(Table[AssociationThread[keys -> RandomChoice[{0, 1, ""} , 30]], 50] )
```

like

[image]

My goal is to generate an operator selecting, for instance, only rows with known key1-key10. But no one straightforward combination works. My attempts

```
data[AllTrue /* Select, keys[[1 ;; 10]], ! StringQ@# &] (* does not work*)
data[Select, AllTrue, keys[[1 ;; 10]], ! StringQ@# &]  (* does not work*)
```

... et.c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to express the selection criteria within a subquery:

```
data[Select[Query[keys[[1;;10]] /* AllTrue[Not@*StringQ]]]]
```

For example, using a smaller dataset for presentation purposes...

```
SeedRandom[0];
{rows, cols} = {10, 10};
keys = "key" ~~ (ToString@#) & /@ Range[cols];
data = Dataset[Table[AssociationThread[keys -> RandomChoice[{0, 1, ""}, cols]], rows]]
```

[image: initial dataset]

... we can query for rows where the first four columns are all not strings:

```
data[Select[Query[keys[[1;;4]] /* AllTrue[Not@*StringQ]]]]
```

[image: filtered dataset]